# Interactive local notifications stopped working

Tags: ios, push-notification

I just added interactive local notifications to my app a few weeks ago. It was great for a while, and then suddenly we noticed that the buttons on the notices disappeared. The code hasn't been touched in a while, but poking around today I verified that the code hasn't changed. However, the interactive buttons are gone. Additionally, I tried pasting in sample code from a tutorial, and that code also fails to produce a local push with buttons (it just produces a non-interactive push).

I've gone back over the commit history, but there's 3 of us working on this app, and no obvious culprits. **Has anyone had this experience before and know what might have happened. What are some obvious culprits I should be checking?**

Comment: May i know the iOS version you are using at the moment?

Comment: The only reason I can think of for your notification to not have buttons anymore is that the code to register the category has gone haywire. You might want to double check for the code that creates UIUserNotificationCategory objects and registers these categories with UIUserNotificationSettings?

Comment: Did iOS had an update in these few weeks? If so, check what changed in these updates. If not did you install other applications recently that might have conflicted with your application. Did the settings changed in these few weeks? And what version of ios do you currently have?

Comment: does this link helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20247372/ios-push-notifications-have-stopped-working ?

Comment: or this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15595720/apple-push-notification-not-working-in-production